# Is there anything similar to "self" inside a Python generator?

Tags: python, coroutine

Is there any way to get a reference to the returned generator object, inside the generator's definition? This would be akin to the `self` argument passed to the method inside the `__next__` method of an iterator. After browsing Python's documentation, I have not found anything similar to it.

This question arose while I was exploring how of much of the following paper's ideas I can implement in Python using generators as coroutines. Paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.19.79

The closest I could do was the following, using a decorator, which builds on David Beazley's `coroutine` decorator, but it feels like a bit of a hack.

```
from functools import wraps


def coroutine(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        f = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(f)
        f.send(f)
        return f
    return decorated


@coroutine
def A():
    self = yield
    # do stuff...
```

---

EDIT: The following class, based on the answer below, can be used as a decorator to have the generator receive a reference to `self` as its first paramter. It has the added benefit that any generator decorated with it will have the type `coroutine`.

```
class coroutine(object):
    """Decorator class for coroutines with a self parameter."""
    def __new__(cls, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            o = object.__new__(cls)
            o.__init__(func, args, kwargs)
            return o
        return decorated

    def __init__(self, generator, args, kw):
        self.generator = generator(self, *args, **kw)
        next(self.generator)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.generator)

    next = __next__

    def send(self, value):
        return self.generator.send(value)


# Usage:

@coroutine
def A(self):
    while True:
        message = yield
        print self is message


a = A()
b = A()
a.send(a)  # outputs True
a.send(b)  # outputs False
```

Comment: I've briefly skimmed about a third of the paper, and I didn't see anything for which you'd want a coroutine to have a reference to itself. It looked like you'd want a coroutine to be able to trigger the coroutine at any given index, though. Is this accurate, or should I go back and actually read the paper instead of skimming?

Comment: If you do want a coroutine to have a reference to itself, what would you use it for? Would the coroutine pass itself as a callback to some other part of the code?

Comment: can you put some used case, actually I am not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Interesting question (+1). Given how esoteric the requirement is, your solution doesn't strike me as being half-bad. That said, it would indeed be interesting to see if someone can come up with something neater...

Comment: It would also be interesting to understand your exact use case for this.

Comment: user2357112: I was trying to have the coroutines construct the "graph" of the coroutines as they went along, instead of having a "driver" that constructs all the coroutines and connects them to each other prior to them executing. You are right in saying that strictly speaking, what I am asking for is not needed by the algorithms in the paper, but with it, the role of the "driver" is reduced, which is more in line with Knuth's view on coroutines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an suggestion using a proxy.

```
def selfDecorator(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        return SelfGenerator(func, args, kw)
    return wrap

class SelfGenerator(object):
    """This class implements the generator interface"""
    def __init__(self, generator, args, kw):
        self.generator = generator(self, *args, **kw)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.generator)
    next = __next__
    def send(self, value):
        return self.generator.send(value)

@selfDecorator
def gen(self, x): # your generator function with self
    for i in range(x):
        yield self


for x in gen(5):
    print x # prints <__main__.SelfGenerator object at 0x02BB16D0>
```

Since `SelfGenerator` is a proxy to the original generator it has the same interface and can be used totally as the Pythons own generator.

**First Answer**

You can not call a generator in itself:

```
>>> def generator():
    for value in g:
        yield value


>>> g = generator()
>>> next(g)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    next(g)
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 2, in generator
    for value in g:
ValueError: generator already executing
```

Guessing: The self in the paper may not mean the generator itself but an object, some state holder that maybe is shared between some generators.

> More precisely, the directed graph of constraints is required to be cycle-free when it is regarded as an undirected graph.

This makes me think that the generator does not refer to its 'identical' execution. Why should it get its own value out of itself by iterating? It can use a local variable.

Coroutines originate from Simula. Maybe to understand what the self is you can have a look at the language.

Comment: Do you have a citation for “Coroutines originate from Simula”? A quick scan of the relevant pages on Wikipedia is decidedly ambiguous; it's possible that Simula was merely an early adopter. (A _very_ early adopter.)

Comment: No, I do not have a citation. It became my knowledge when reading something about the history of object-orientation. By my knowledge it is the first adopter. (= origin) Maybe the first successful adopter. I wrote this because I am not sure what Sahand means with 'self'. A running generator referring to itself makes no sense to me.

Comment: I just asked because I was curious, and because a quick scan of WP wasn't clear. (I'm not at work so I can't easily directly read the literature that far back.) I find it fascinating that coros are a feature that was long out of favour, and yet which has enjoyed something of a renaissance in recent years.

Comment: Your decorator solution is quite nice. EDIT: Never mind, it does work with `send`! Nice. As for the generator not being able to call itself, yes absolutely. And that is not the intent here. Later on in the paper, there are algorithms in which a "troll" needs a reference to both the previous and next "troll" (a troll is basically a coroutine here). To avoid having to construct the coroutines in advance, I was trying to get a reference to "self" which can be passed to newly created coroutines as their "previous" reference.

Comment: If you have results could you also update this post? I would like to see how you track the co-routines and reason about the graph. Tracking co-routines when passed to other co-routines should be possible when using this proxy.